# How would I get these javascript values and use them in an image source?

Tags: javascript, jquery, variables, shopping-cart

My shopping cart solution passes these post-transaction variables to my thank you page's `<head>`...

```
var SecureCartOrders = [ {"orderID":237203170,"name":"asdfasdf","Total":1.00} ];
```

And I need them to load them in an image tracking pixel's source (to send the data to another system).

The tracking pixel is initially loaded as so...

```
<img id="iDev" src="" width="1" height="1" border="0">
```

And with a script I'm trying to set the source with those order variables...

```
<script>

var imgSrc = "http://www.idevaffiliate.com/32323/sale.php?profile=32&idev_saleamt=" + Total + '&idev_ordernum=' + orderID;

window.onload = function() {
      document.getElementById("iDev").src=imgSrc;
    } 

</script>
```

However, my script is failing to get those variables from the script my shopping cart gives.

The result it needs to create is to set the image source with those variables like this...

```
<img id="iDev" src="http://www.idevaffiliate.com/32323/sale.php?profile=32&idev_saleamt=1.00&idev_ordernum=237203170" width="1" height="1" border="0">
```

How would I be able to do that, with the way my shopping cart lays out those variables?

Thanks :)

Comment: I fail to see a single connection between `SecureCartOrders` and `imgSrc`...

Comment: That script with `SecureCartOrders` is what my shopping cart creates, and I have no control of that. I'm trying to access the data in that script to build that image's source.

Comment: I understand what each of them does, but I don't see any relation between them in your example. What maps to what?

Comment: The image is a tracking pixel for an affiliate management system. This tracking pixel goes on a thank you page, and pings the affiliate system when a sale is made, sending it the order's total and id, through the tracking pixel's source.

Comment: Again, I understand how it works, but I can't see a relation between `{"orderID":237203170,"name":"Jonathan Denney","Total":1.00}` and `http://www.idevaffiliate.com/32323/sale.php?profile=32&idev_saleamt=`

Comment: I'm trying to build the image source like this `src="http://www.idevaffiliate.com/32323/sale.php?profile=32&idev_saleamt=1.00&idev_ordernum=237203170"`. The url parameters like `idev_ordernum` are for the affiliate tracking system's use. Help me understand what between the relationship you don't exactly understand, so I can better explain.

Comment: Got it now! Why don't you append the parameters to the base url?

Comment: How would I do that?

Comment: Sorry, I missed the `" + Total + '&idev_ordernum=' + orderID` part because it was off-page. Added an answer...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on what you said in the comments, you need to append the data to the image src variable:

```js
var SecureCartOrders = [{
  "orderID": 237203170,
  "name": "Jonathan Denney",
  "Total": 1.00
}];
var imgSrc = "http://www.idevaffiliate.com/32323/sale.php?profile=32&idev_saleamt=" + SecureCartOrders[0].Total + '&idev_ordernum=' + SecureCartOrders[0].orderID;

window.onload = function() {
  //document.getElementById("iDev").src=imgSrc;
  alert(imgSrc);
}
```

Comment: You're welcome, sorry once again about the whole confusion in the comments. :)